# Convert mapped or UNC path to http url

Tags: c#, url, pdf, webdav, unc

I have an issue where pdf files don't open on edge when they come from a WebDAV address.

I have noticed however that if I hit the file directly using the url for the file the pdf opens correctly as required.

I was wondering if there is a way to convert either of the following paths into the url required.

Paths I have:

> - Z:\Folder\TestPDF.pdf
> - \\127.0.0.1@1234\DavWWWRoot\Folder\TestPDF.pdf

URL I want

> - http://127.0.0.1:1234/Folder/TestPDF.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use URI class

```
var uri = new System.Uri(@"Z:\Folder\TestPDF.pdf").AbsoluteUri;
```

The result is URI path what you want:  file:///Z:/Folder/TestPDF.pdf

Comment: It does not work with file:// unfortunately, only when you go to http://127.0.0.1:1234/Folder/TestPDF.pdf